# cakephp 2.x how to include files from external template css

Tags: html, css, templates, cakephp

I have this external HTML template (that I got from `themeforest`):

[image: html template]

The directory structure looks like this:

```
base/
- css/
- fonts/
- images/
- img/
- js/
- index.html
```

Template **Index.html** uses `css` like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" id="color-switcher-link">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animations.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fonts.css">
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
```

I dont know how to properly copy files; should they go from `css` to server web root? Or into `cakephp/app/` or `cakephp/app/webroot/css/`?

In cake I have `Views/Layouts/` and `View/Layouts/Pages/home.ctp`. I created `mainpage.ctp` which is `index.html` from template and try to combine it with `home.ctp` but it looks crappy:

[image: crappy]

Any suggestions?

Comment: CSS files belong in the `webroot/css` folder. In your template file you can load them by using `$this->Html->css('bootstrap.min.css')`. It will load the file out the webroot CSS folder. Check the cookbook https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#using-blocks-for-script-and-css-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two option

**first option**

copy your theme `base` folder into `webroot`  Then go to your `src/template/layout/default.ctp` and include them like the following example

Let say in your `html` template there is css call like

`<link href="./base/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

Replace it with

`<?= $this->Html->css('../base/css/base') ?>`

Same with js

`<?= $this->Html->script('../base/js/plugin'); ?>`

Note : You don't need to put file extension `.css` or `.js`

**Option 2**

Copy each css files into webroot/css

Copy each JS files into webroot/js

call the file directly

For calling base.css

`<?= $this->Html->css('base') ?>`

For calling plugin.js

`<?= $this->Html->script('plugin'); ?>`

In **cakephp 3** you can change the path of each folder from your `config/app.php`

`'     imageBaseUrl' => 'img/',
        'cssBaseUrl' => 'css/',
        'jsBaseUrl' => 'js/'`